# Yii2 - Quiz - Work with many-to-many table

Tags: php, yii2, many-to-many

I need development something similar a quiz.
I have 3 tables:
`quiz`, `quiz_questions`, `quiz_questions_answers`.

I render the questions / answers like this in form.

```
<?php foreach ($modelQuestions as $modelQuestion): ?>
            <?= $modelQuestion->question ?> <br/>
            <?= $form->field($modelMatch, 'answer[]')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

in controller i need save `id_quiz` and `obs` in table `quiz`, but i need save in many-to-many table `quiz_questions_answers` like `id_quiz`, `id_question` and `answer` for each answers.

I'm trying this in foreach loop, but how i get the "id_question" for each answer?

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Quiz();
        $modelMatch = new QuizQuestionsAnswers();
        $modelQuestions = QuizQuestions::find()->all();


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelMatch->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            $model->save();

            foreach ($modelMatch->answer as $answer) {
                    $modelMatch = new QuizQuestionsAnswers();
                    $modelMatch->id_quis = $model->id;
                    $modelMatch->id_question = ????;
                    $modelMatch->answer = $answer;
                    $modelMatch->save();
            }

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modelMatch' => $modelMatch,
                'modelQuestions' => $modelQuestions,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

this is a scenario create, and after i need prepare this for the scenario update.
i'm lost..

the schema database is:

[image]

Comment: what are you looking for currently?, what looks like you are currently trying to create a quiz ? is that so? then you might have to save the question first and the relative choices/answers for that question on the second number and then the quiz itself. you will have to keep track of the answers with the question for which they are using the tabular inputs for the answers.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam im trying save `quiz` in first, and then after save the `answers` in many-to-many table. look my foreach, i need `id_question` for the many-to-many table

Comment: you can save the quiz first but you have to save the questions first in order to get the id and then save all the answers against that question.can you add your table schema for making things more clear

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam the table with question is already defined in db. I update de quesion and add picture with table schema.

Comment: added an answer see if it helps you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `id_question` as the hidden input and pre-populate the field as you have the question already saved in the database and use tabular approach for field names you should have the `[]` in the start not in the end, also you should group the answer with the question by using the `$modelQuestions` index so the answer and the question that it belongs to all are in separate arrays see the below code

```
<?php foreach ($modelQuestions as $index=>$modelQuestion): ?>
    <?php echo $modelQuestion->question ?> <br/>
    <?php echo $form->field($modelMatch, "[$index]answer")->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
    <?php echo Html::activeHiddenInput($model,"[$index]id_question",['value'=>$modelQuestion->id]) ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Now when you will submit your for you will see the answers in the post array like below

```
Array(
.....
    'QuizQuestionsAnswers'=>[
        [0]=>[

            'answer'=>'some answer'
            'id_question'=>1,
        ],
        [1]=>[
            'answer'=>'some answer',
            'id_question'=>2,
        ],
    ],
.....
)
```

Now you should save every answer. And for doing this you should use the `transactions` so that if any of the answers is not validated according to the model rules it should throw an error and should not save any of the answers or the quiz.

So you should change the code to the below

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Quiz();
    $modelMatch = new QuizQuestionsAnswers();
    $modelQuestions = QuizQuestions::find()->all();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();

        try {
            if (!$model->save()) {
                throw new \Exception(implode("<br />", ArrayHelper::getColumn($model->errors, '0')));
            }

            foreach (Yii::$app->request->post('QuizQuestionsAnswers', []) as $answer) {
                $modelMatch = new QuizQuestionsAnswers();
                $modelMatch->id_quis = $model->id;
                $modelMatch->id_question = $answer['id_question'];
                $modelMatch->answer = $answer['answer'];
                if (!$modelMatch->save()) {
                    throw new \Exception(implode("<br />", ArrayHelper::getColumn($modelMatch->errors, '0')));
                }
            }

            $transaction->commit();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $transaction->rollBack();
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger', $e->getMessage());
        }

    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelMatch' => $modelMatch,
        'modelQuestions' => $modelQuestions
    ]);

}
```

Comment: you completely correct as always! I really appreciate your help. this part of code `Yii::$app->request->post('QuizQuestionsAnswers', [])` solved almost everything. thanks!